# Learning APIs: cant read property of forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to learn the ins and outs of using APIs and this is my first attempt. I am able to get the data from the api but when I try to display it on the webpage via a `forEach` loop the console says that the `forEach` property is `undefined`. How can I fix this?

```js
document.querySelector('.get-player').addEventListener('click', getPlayers);

function getPlayers(e) {
  let request;
  const input1 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
  const api = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=';
  let sum = api + input1;

  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', sum, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    let info = JSON.parse(this.response);
    let output = '';
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      console.log(info);
      info.value.forEach(function(data) {
        output += `<li>${data.position}</li>`;
      });
    } else {
      console.log(input1.value);
    }

    document.querySelector('.position').innerHTML = output;
  }

  request.send();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Your error means whatever you are trying to iterate through is not an `array` since `forEach` is an `array` method.

Comment: Please post a snippet of your response json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your code, you were trying to iterate through `info.value` but `info` does not have a key called `value`, the correct key was `data`. I have corrected your code at the relevant place:

**forEach is an array method, trying to use it on an undefined value will throw an error.**

Read more about forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
document.querySelector('.get-player').addEventListener('click', getPlayers);

function getPlayers(e) {
  let request;
  const input1 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
  const api = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=';
  let sum = api + input1;

  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', sum, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    let info = JSON.parse(this.response);
    let output = '';
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      console.log(info);
      info.data.forEach(function(data) {                 //REPLACE VALUE BY DATA
        output += `<li>${data.position}</li>`;
      });
    } else {
      console.log(input1.value);
    }

    document.querySelector('.position').innerHTML = output;
  }

  request.send();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually quite clear*:

> TypeError: info.value is undefined

Your `info` object does not have a `value` property, as you can see in the console. You'll probably want to iterate `.data` instead:

```js
document.querySelector('.get-player').addEventListener('click', getPlayers);

function getPlayers(e) {
  let request;
  const input1 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
  const api = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=';
  let sum = api + input1;

  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', sum, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    let info = JSON.parse(this.response);
    //console.log(info);
    let output = '';
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      info.data.forEach(function(data) {
        output += `<li>${data.position}</li>`;
      });
    } else {
      console.log(input1.value);
    }

    document.querySelector('.position').innerHTML = output;
  }

  request.send();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button class="get-player">get player</button>
<ul class="position"></ul>
```

**at least that's what I got running your code. If it actually said something different about `forEach` being `undefined`, then there's something differing between the code you provided and your actual production code.*

Comment: If this solved your issue, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

actually you are accessing wrong key from `info` object

actual **response** contains `array` named `data`

and you are accessing `value` which is `undefined` hence can't be iterated.